# SQL Server Xml Namespace Querying Problem

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, namespaces, xpath

I have the following in an xml variable `@ResultData`

```
<EntityKey_x005B__x005D_>
  <EntityKey>
    <KeyData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey">
      <KeyField>
        <Field>JournalNum</Field>
        <Value>LJRN000071</Value>
      </KeyField>
    </KeyData>
  </EntityKey>
  <EntityKey>
    <KeyData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey">
      <KeyField>
        <Field>JournalNum</Field>
        <Value>LJRN000072</Value>
      </KeyField>
    </KeyData>
  </EntityKey>
  <EntityKey>
    <KeyData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey">
      <KeyField>
        <Field>JournalNum</Field>
        <Value>LJRN000073</Value>
      </KeyField>
    </KeyData>
  </EntityKey>
  <EntityKey>
    <KeyData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey">
      <KeyField>
        <Field>JournalNum</Field>
        <Value>LJRN000074</Value>
      </KeyField>
    </KeyData>
  </EntityKey>
</EntityKey_x005B__x005D_>
```

But I can't seem to select the JournalNum values from it because of the `xmlns=...` on the node.  In .Net I can do something like `"{http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey}KeyData"` to retrieve it, but I get a syntax error in SQL.

I just want to get a list of the Value nodes, in document order into a temp table and this doesn't work either....

```
SELECT  IDENTITY(int,1,1) as 'ID',
    c.query('(KeyData/KeyField/Value)[1]') as 'JournalNum'
INTO    #tmpBatches
FROM    @ResultData.nodes('//EntityKey') t(c)
```

Thoughts? Suggestions? Solutions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got it...of course, right after asking

```
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey' as DYN)
    SELECT  IDENTITY(int,1,1)   
                as 'ID',
            c.value('(DYN:KeyData/DYN:KeyField/DYN:Value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(40)')
                as 'JournalNum'
    INTO    #tmpBatches
    FROM    @ResultData.nodes('//EntityKey') t(c)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have finally gotten rid of these pesky namespaces in my xpath queries.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one namespace, you could have used DEFAULT to avoid having to prefix everywhere:

```
 ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey') 
        SELECT   IDENTITY(int,1,1)                                                
        as 'ID', c.value('(<strike>DYN:</strike>KeyData/DYN:KeyField/DYN:Value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(40)')
        as 'JournalNum'
            INTO #tmpBatches
        FROM @ResultData.nodes('//EntityKey') t(c)
```

Also, some notes I stumbled across on how to ignore all namespaces for when there are more than one and you KNOW you will have no collisions.
[Someone's blog.](http://blog.jontav.com/post/11396385355/ignore-xml-namespaces-in-t-sql)